# Замена текста python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте!
Есть такая задача - заменить несколько слов в тексте результатом функции. (функция всегда возвращает различные значение)

т.е. предположительный алгоритм -

```
#считаем количество слов в тексте
num_of_words = text.count('word')
#пытаемся их заменить в цикле
for i in xrange(1, num_of_words):
    text = text.replace('word', some_function())
```

И получается что при первом прохождении цикла он заменяет все существующие слова для замены одним и тем же значением, какую функцию замены нужно использовать или как, чтобы осуществить задуманное?
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: согласен с @alexlz

Comment: @alexlz оформи как ответ, сделаю принятым

Comment: В xrange() первым параметром нужно передавать 0. Иначе количество замен будет на единицу меньше, чем количество слов в тексте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Укажите в replace счётчик замен 1.

```
 text = text.replace('word', some_function(), 1)
```

Но в результате some_function(), разумеется, не должно быть 'word'

Comment: Тормозное это решение, однако.

Comment: Мне нужно всего около 11 элементов заменять на типичной html странице, думаю это не сильно отразится на быстродействии.
Еще раз благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 5):

Могу предложить такое решение

```
strlist=test.split('word')
test=strlist[0]
for i in strlist[1:]:
    test=some_function().join((test, i))
```

По моим измерениям работает быстрее, чем исходный вариант, примерно на 15%

Comment: И ещё плюс. В заменах может присутствовать 'word', чего в исходном варианте было делать нельзя.

Comment: Совершенно верно

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще при помощи регулярных выражений:

```
import re
def some_function(val):
    return val.group(0).upper()

arr=["mama", "papa", "i"]
text= "..."
for i in arr:
    text=re.sub(re.escape(i), some_function, text)
```